# How to pass Hidden field id value pass action link?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Here is my `Hidden` field id set by viewbag:

```
if (@ViewBag.GoveerNo != null)
        {
             @Html.Hidden("govern_no", (int)@ViewBag.GoveerNo)

        }
```

I want to pass `govern_no` Hidden value in the action link parameter `govern_no`. How can I do it?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "City", new { govern_no = }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `@ViewBag.GoveerNo` directly in your `ActrionLink` method like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Index", "City", new { govern_no = ViewBag.GoveerNo }, new { @class = "btn btn-success" })
```

Like that there is no need to retrieve the value from the hidden field.